# How to make Watson Conversation Api Invoke a web Application Url when User Enters an Input?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, bots, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have a spring mvc application and I would like to make my user call a bot and the bot based on user input should access a url and based on the response provide an answer.How could I achieve this in Java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it. However, Watson Conversation does provide a mechanism to handle such requests.
You will need to tell the calling Java app that a url needs to be invoked.

This is done by using two features:
Context.request 
skip_user_input

A `request` is a special context variable that has args, name and result.
It is used to tell the calling app that it should do some action based on this variable.

Setting `skip_user_input` is optional. In many cases, you might want to execute some business logic in your application and then provide its results via `result`. Setting `skip_user_input` to true, will tell Watson Conversation to not wait for input from the user. Thus, your condition on the next node should be based on the content inside `result`.

```
{
  "output": {},
  "context": {
    "request": {
      "args": {
        "url_to_invoke": "your_url"
      },
      "name": "Call_A_URL",
      "result": "context.response"
    },
    "skip_user_input": true
  }
}
```

Comment: To accomplish the above  you will need to click on Watson Response -> Advanced

Comment: How do I invoke the Watson Conversation via a phone call

Comment: @briantaurostack7 could you elaborate? you can use Watson STT and TTS  along side Watson Conversation. I suggest you open a different question for this.

Comment: @Dudi should my application look for "skip_user_input" in the context and decide to call the Conversation Service immediately ? Or does the Conversation Service itself proceed to the next node, in which case I don't understand how the request gets executed ...

Comment: Your app needs to handle the request, it will typically update some context variable. conversation will auto skip the input in the next api invocation. As it sees skip_user in the api call

Comment: Hi, friends. I have a similar problem: trying to put a single html input (type e-mail) inside a conversation dialog. Watson conversation does not capture the typed value into a context variable. Must I use this kind of context request, in order to obtain the typed email? Obs: I have also put a submit button below the input field.

Comment: Hello, can anyone please suggest an example for the same?

Comment: @Dudi please suggest an example for the same?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now available, with the help of IBM cloud functions. The [link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions?cm_sp=dw-bluemix-_-nospace-_-answers) has the details of the implementation.