# how can I call a webservice from watson conversation?

Tags: watson-conversation

I want to invoke a webservice within watson-conversation response and display the returned result from webservice to client.

For example, if I ask watson this question: 
how about the weather in New York 2016-12-30 ?

then watson will invoke a weather related webservice and pass the parameters city(New York) and date(2016-12-30) to the webservice, the webservice will return message "It is sunny, temperature is 30".

The client will get "It is sunny, temperature is 30" as the answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263747/how-to-make-watson-conversation-api-invoke-a-web-application-url-when-user-enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to checkout the weather bot built with Watson Conversation and the Weather API.
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-bot

Comment: Is it possible to call SOAP API from Watson conversation application ,[for this sample](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple) ,which is deployed in nodejs?