# can we make Watson call external API to retrieve relevant response data, instead of loading whole data in html, json or txt format

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

When user asks a question to Watson, it should use AI to decouple the question and call respective API which handles retrieving data from database (SQL).

For example:

- I have list of movies, actors, no of times each movie is watched etc stored in rational database like SQL.
- I have an API for getting the actors in the movie(which quesries the database).

Suppose if a user asks Watson "give me list of all actors in the movie XXX". Watson should call API which returns the response back.

Is it possible to perform an action like this with IBM Watson?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this in your application layer. Within the conversation you can tell your application about such a request by using the context.request. see [How to make Watson Conversation Api Invoke a web Application Url when User Enters an Input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263747/how-to-make-watson-conversation-api-invoke-a-web-application-url-when-user-enter)