# Open URL in IBM Watson conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am using a Blumix free account to develop a chat-bot using watson conversation.

How do I add a clickable URL in the response, or automatically call a URL in browser?

I have edited the "advanced response" using the suggestions as described [on this page](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/306133/want-to-enter-and-url-in-watson-conversation-respo.html) but could not get it work.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi, what programming language are you using? Node.js, java?

Comment: I am using the GUI Interface, i.e. I dont need to code for it. Example Interface: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*MYDX5bGngxJ6ntTziWt2Fg.png

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but.. if you wants add some url `inside` flows Conversation Service (IBM Watson), try it:

**1º: Add the url with tag `<a target>` and `href=` your URL inside flows. See the example:**

[image]

**JSON:**

```
"output": {
            "text": "This is a link <a  target=\"_blank\" href= \"https://www.choosemyplate.gov\">Food and nutrition Guide</a>.\n<br/><br/>Talk to you later, bye for now!"
        },
```

**2º See that it did not work *inside* the Conversation, because it will be your browser that will `render` the `html`.**

[image]

**3º If you open with your browser, it works, see:**

[image]

See that the link is showing up, and this will work for other things in html, like button, for example...

**But if you can: based on user input should access a url:**

This is done by using two features: `Context.request` `skip_user_input`

A request is a special context variable that has args, name and result. It is used to tell the `calling app` that it should do some action based on this variable.

Setting `skip_user_input` is optional. In many cases, you might want to execute some business logic in your application and then provide its results via `result`. Setting `skip_user_input` to `true`, will tell Watson Conversation to not wait for input from the user. Thus, your condition on the next node should be based on the content inside result.

```
 {
      "output": {},
      "context": {
        "request": {
          "args": {
            "url_to_invoke": "your_url"


  },
      "name": "Call_A_URL",
      "result": "context.response"
    },
    "skip_user_input": true
  }
}
```

Reference: IBM Professional **@Dudi**: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263747/how-to-make-watson-conversation-api-invoke-a-web-application-url-when-user-enter).