# Insert hyperlink inside Watson dialog conversation

Tags: android, watson-assistant

I'm programming a dialog with Watson conversation API. And now I want to insert a hyperlink inside the dialog box.

I tried these solutions [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/288264/how-do-i-include-a-hyperlink-to-an-external-web-pa.html) and [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/305420/how-do-i-make-a-hyperlink-to-another-dialog-node-i.html), but they don't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you can do this inside **Conversation flow**. Add or replace the text inside JSON.
Add the url with tag `<a target>` and `href=` your URL inside flows.

Check my example (EDIT with example inside conversation flow):

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "This is a link <a  target=\\\"_blank\\\" href= \\\"https://www.choosemyplate.gov\\\">Food and nutrition Guide</a>.\\n<br/><br/>Talk to you later, bye for now!"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

See more in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634296/open-url-in-watson-converstaion/42007219#42007219) link.
I answered the same question with more details.

Add inside your response (not advanced response):

```
<a  target="_blank" href="https://google.com.br">Google</a>.\n<br/><br/>
```

If you have more questions about this, let me know, I'll try help you.

Comment: cna you insert a valid json pls?

Comment: I inserted this, but it's not clickable, it's not a hyperlink

Comment: Inside Service Watson conversation show all the html, but if you open the conversation, it works. Check my link with all details

Comment: i'm using a chat in android to test it, so i want it to be used inside my chat.

Comment: In the case isn't Watson Conversation Problem, because it works for me with various app's. Maybe is something that you must add inside your code. 
Check this answer [with android link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)