# IBM Watson: How do I add a hyperlink to Watson Responses?

Tags: json, watson-conversation, watson

I've tried other responses mentioned on other forums but I'm still not able to get the right result.

As of this moment,  [this is what the layout looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEAQS.png)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in your *Watson response* the HTML tag, the browser will render:

```
The link to go to google is: click <a  target="_blank" href="https://google.com.br">Google</a>.<br/><br/>
```

**Add inside Watson response:**

[image]
Tested hyperlink:

[image]

Obs.: Check inside Try it out, this does not work, but inside your Web application, all will works fine. This is valid for other `<html>` tag, for example: `<button>`, etc

I Answer the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554222/insert-hyperlink-inside-watson-dialog-conversation/42555676#42555676).
Answer with more details and images [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634296/open-url-in-watson-converstaion/42007219#42007219).

Comment: Is the output from Watson Virtual Agent or your own custom chat interface? I am trying it out in Virtual Agent but I can't get it to show up as a hyperlink - the html markup itself shows

Comment: In this case, my custom chat interface, web page. Depends what is your channel, like messenger, for example, the link works only if you send directly `https://yourwebsite.com`

Comment: Ok good to know. What I have experienced so far is that Watson Virtual Agent does not show them as links

Comment: Did you add in the `response` my example? Try to use just the `< a href></a>` tagged with the link.

Comment: I did. Watson Virtual Agent Widget does not show it as a link

Answer (score 0):

replace the "quotation marks" around the link with 'apostrophe'

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "say something <a href='http://www.website.com/'>link text</a>"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the hyperlink through the `context`

Example (using python at backend) -

```
response['context']['link'] = "www.google.com"
conversation.message(workspace_id=workspace_id,
    message_input={'text': user_input},
    context=response['context'])
```

Now in your dialog

```
{
  "context": {},
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "$link"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

So the values you pass in `context` are displayed prefix `$`

Comment: Link can directly be added to watson conversation response