# How to redirect user to human in stamplay watson/intercom integration

Tags: watson-conversation, intercom, stamplay

I'm making a demo of chatbot for my company and trying to made using IBM conversation API, and Intercom with stamplay webhook, and I have one question, when I created the project he asks me "Pick the Intercom account that will take over the conversation if the user asks to talk to a human", and my question is, how do I setup it? What my user need to say to talk to a human? Where I setup this? And if I want that when Watson does not find any answers to redirected user to a human?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, 
I suggest to create one `intent` with examples to how to ask to talk with humans, and inside the last node flow, you will create one context variable with the value `true` like:

```
{
  "context": {
    "verified": true;
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Please wait and you will talk with someone."
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

And after it, you can [create one condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725072/how-do-i-add-an-action-to-watson-conversation-response/42725475#42725475) inside your code to do someting like:

```
var userWantsHuman = context.verified;
if (userWantHuman === true {
//start conversation intercom
//do something inside your app
}
```

You will redirect the user for the Intercom conversation, or you can simply add the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622965/ibm-watson-how-do-i-add-a-hyperlink-to-watson-responses/43641653#43641653) to user click to talk with a human, and the link will redirect o your chatapp (Intercom).

Comment: Check out Watson virtual agent. It has built in mechanism to call agent so u dont need to come up with your own sentences for calling agents