# Does Watson Conversation service support SOAP API?

Tags: soap, watson-conversation, watson

I am planning of making a dynamic conversation service using SOAP API integrated to my Watson Conversation service.
I would like to know if SOAP API is supported in Watson Conversation.I know that REST API is supported [doc under the section TIME Zone they mention REST API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/system-entities.html).

I would like to know if SOAP API is also supported.
The main reason for the question is since SOAP is by default in XML and REST API is mainly in JSON.The Watson Conversation Service is in JSON.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263747/how-to-make-watson-conversation-api-invoke-a-web-application-url-when-user-enter)   answer too but this doesn't mention if using REST or SOAP API.

Comment: to my knowledge there is no SOAP api

Comment: [With this](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-soap) it is possible to integrate SOAP api.